# List of non-squares using "list comprehension" in Perl 6

Tags: list-comprehension, raku

How can I create a list of non-squares (i.e. integers whose square roots are not integers) using "list comprehension" in Perl 6? I came across the [following code from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sequence_of_Non-squares#Perl_6) showing how to print a list of non-squares.

```
sub nth_term (Int $n) { $n + round sqrt $n }

say nth_term $_ for 1 .. 22;
```

My understanding of list comprehension is that it is a declarative way, similar to [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), to describe a list in a programming language.

The closest thing that I've noticed so far is using the `for` keyword. But since this is really just an in-line loop, I thought that this wasn't technically list comprehension, even though it seems similar:

```
my @y = ($_**2 + 1 for 1 .. 10);
```

But, what I'd really like to know is if there is a "list comprehension" way of creating any mathematically describable list such as non-squares. Here's how I would create a list of non-squares imperatively (up to 30):

```
my @non_squares = grep {sqrt($_) != floor(sqrt($_))}, 1 .. 30;
```

How could I do this as a list comprehension?

Comment: Very muddy question and not so great answer. I hope to rewrite them some day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your example of `my @y = ($_**2 + 1 for 1 .. 10);` is a Perl 6 way of writing list comprehensions. You can also add a conditional test, as suggested in the [Perl 6 design document S04](http://design.perl6.org/S04.html#Loop_statements):

> for ease of writing list comprehensions, a looping statement modifier is allowed to contain a single conditional statement modifier:
>   ...
>   `@evens = ($_ * 2 if .odd for 0..100);`

Here's how to write a Perl 6 list comprehension of non-squares (up to 30):

```
my @non_squares = ($_ if .sqrt != .sqrt.Int for 1 .. 30);
```

---

*A little explanation:* In each iteration of the `for` loop, the current number in the range from 1 to 30 is assigned to the default variable `$_` (a.k.a. "it"). Method invocations without an invocant get called on "it" by default (i.e. `.sqrt` is the same as `$_.sqrt`). So for each number in the range 1 to 30, its square root is checked to see if it is has a non-integer square root. If true, then it is included in the list.

Comment: `(1..30).grep: { .sqrt != .sqrt.Int }` may be clearer to read from left to right.  `(1..30).grep: { $_ != .Int with $^n.sqrt }` will possibly be faster because it only needs to do the `.sqrt` once for each number.